# Is it possible to pass undeclared variables as parameters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typeof

Let's say I have a variable `myvar`, and I *don't* have a variable `myvar2`. I can run the following without a problem:

```
typeof myvar
// ⇒ 'string'
typeof myvar2
// ⇒ 'undefined'
```

`typeof` and `delete` are the only functions I know of which don't throw errors when given an undefined parameter like this. I looked at [the language spec for `typeof`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) and to my uninitiated eyes it seems to use internal functions like `IsUnresolvableReference`.

> <sup>**Edit**: I'd been working in a language that checks type with [a synonymous function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/typeof.html), and hadn't noticed `typeof` is actually an operator in JavaScript. I've removed parentheses from the code here but left the above as written.</sup>

When I create a function:

```
function myFunc(input_variable) {
  return("hello");
}
```

... as expected this throws a `ReferenceError` when passed `myvar2` as a parameter, unless I run `var myvar2;`.

If I wrap the return in a `try`/`catch` statement to handle the *myvar2 not defined* case, I still get the same error, as the variable seems to be checked for a resolvable reference upon entry into the function (upon runtime?) :

```
function myFunc(input_var) {
  try {
    return "hello";
  } catch(error) {
    if (error.name === 'ReferenceError'){
      return "world";
    }
  }
}
```

I was wondering how I can make a function that accepts unresolved references. My general guess is that, if it's a standard behaviour of functions, then perhaps I could modify some prototype for this construction specifically...? I'm aware prototypes are for objects, I'm wondering if this  level of control over `function` is possible somehow?

By way of context, I always find myself writing `function(input_var)` :

```
if (typeof input_var == 'undefined' || my_settings.input_var_is_optional === true)
  var input_var = 'Sometimes variables are optional. This is my default value.';
  return dealWith(input_var);
} else if (typeof input_var == 'string') {
    return dealWith(input_var);
} else {
  // Already checked that input_var isn't optional, so we have a problem
  return false; // or throw a TypeError or something like that
}
```

but the verbosity of all that plain puts me off writing type checking into my code, making it less robust to use functions more freely, or to pass onto other developers.

I'd like to write a type handling function, *e.g.*

> *For a function `myFunc(input_var)`, if the variable passed in as parameter `input_var` has been defined, check if it's a string, else set it as `"default_value"`. If it wasn't defined, also set it as `"default_value"`, else it's a valid string, so just use `input_var` as is.*

...but it's sabotaged by the fact that I can't actually pass anything in that's undefined, effectively stopping me from isolating this complexity in a separate function to which I could just pass 2 parameters: `input_var` (the real deal, not just its name), and `expected_type`.

```
function typeTest(input_var, expected_type) {
  var is_optional_value = (typeof expected_type != 'undefined'
                                                 && expected_type === true);
  var optional_str = is_optional_value ? "|(undefined)" : ''
  var type_test_regex = RegExp('^(?!' + expected_type + optional_str + '$)');
  var is_expected_type = type_test_regex.test(typeof(input_var));
}
```

For example, to check that an optional variable passed into a function was both defined, and was defined as a string,

```
var myvar = 'abc'
//  myvar2 is never defined

// Mandatory type (expecting a string):
typeTest(myvar, 'string'); // true
// if (/^(?!string)$)/.test(typeof(myvar))
typeTest(myvar2, 'string'); // throws error

// Mandatory type (expecting a number):
typeTest(myvar, 'number'); // false
typeTest(myvar2, 'number'); // throws error

// Optional type ("expected is true"):
typeTest(myvar, true); // true
// if (/^(?!string|(undefined)$)/.test(typeof(myvar))
typeTest(myvar2, true); // throws error
```

Comment: Let me ask you this: why would you ever want that? The fact that `typeof(myvar2)` works even when `myvar2` is not defined seems like an epic JavaScript fail to me. BTW: neither `typeof` nor `delete` are functions. These are keywords and that's why this works.

Comment: +1 You should never need to check whether a variable has been _declared_ at runtime.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Optional parameters are useful in functions with default settings. I want to write functions that have default values, like I said above. The thing that wouldn't be declared is the optional parameter - I'd use a default value in its place. Thanks @MichaelP. I'll edit the title.

Comment: @Louis Optional parameters _are_ declared. They just don't have a value. So the premise of your question is flawed.

Comment: @Louis You have wrong understanding of optional parameters in functions. It doesn't assume passing `undefined` values. It assume **omitting** parameters.

Comment: @freakish its not an epic fail of js.You can check whether a variable is defined or not ,without any exceptions

Comment: @hindmost sorry, miscommunication! No, I don't want to handle anything *omitted* this way - just undeclared, as in the `myFunc(input_var)` example I gave, using a default value when `input_var` is undefined, such as `myFunc(var2)`. As I said in the question, this causes an error.

Comment: @Louis function parameters are always declared. In your example you have undeclared **variable** (`var2`), not parameter. Parameter `input_var` just derive this undeclared value.

Comment: @hindmost I know, hence my question asks to "pass undeclared variables as parameters", and I'm aware that `input_var` gets derived from what you pass, I just observed `typeof`/`delete` could handle that situation and was wondering if anything else can exploit what they do, it'd be handy!

Comment: @balajisoundar Check whether a variable is defined in runtime? Are you serious? So basically you failed as a coder, you have no idea what you've just written and you need to check it in runtime. :D Sorry, it is an epic fail. Plus what if you do a typo in `typeof myvar;`? Oh, that's right, it won't throw an exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I was wondering how I can make a function that accepts unresolved references.

You can't. When you access an undeclared variable, the `ReferenceError` occurs before the function even gets called. There's nothing you can do inside the function to recover from this, because it hasn't even been called.

> typeof and delete are the only functions I know of which don't throw errors when given an undefined parameter like this.

`typeof` and `delete` are not functions. That's why.

> For example, to check that an optional variable passed into a function was both defined, and was defined as a string.

There's nothing stopping you from doing this. There is a difference between:

- variables with the value `undefined`
- parameters that have not been passed a value
- undeclared variables.

There is no problem in dealing with the first two:

```js
function hasType(val, type) {
  return typeof val === type;
}

function myFunc(param1, param2) {
  console.log('param1: ', hasType(param1, 'string'));
  console.log('param2: ', hasType(param2, 'string'));
}

myFunc('hello');
```

There is no need to check whether someone is trying to call your functions with *undeclared* variables. If they are, then the problem is with their code and they need to fix it. If they are taking advantage of *optional* parameters, that is a different matter, and you can handle for that scenario just fine.

Answer (score 3):

> as the variable seems to be checked for a resolvable reference upon entry into the function

It is checked **before** entry.

Given `foo(bar)`, the logic for resolution is "Get `foo`, then get `bar`, then call `foo` with the value of `bar` as an argument.

If `bar` isn't declared then you'll get a ReferenceError before the function is called in the first place.

> typeof and delete are the only functions I know of which don't throw errors when given an undefined parameter like this.

From the documentation you link to:

> The typeof **Operator**
>   The delete **Operator**

They aren't functions.

---

> I was wondering how I can make a function that accepts unresolved references.

You can't.

> For example, to check that an optional variable

If you want an argument to be optional then either:

Explicitly pass `undefined`:

```
typeTest(undefined, 'string');
```

Put the optional argument last in the arguments list:

```
typeTest('string');
```

Pass an object:

```
typeTest({ argument_name: 'string' });
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of these workarounds but like I say it makes it messy to repeatedly do this `if(typeof(input_var) !== 'undefined') ...` in the middle of functions

Answer (score 1):

You can using a function slide.

```
function attempt(f){
    console.log(f());
}
attempt( function (){ return  nomansland} );
//later an ajax call declares it:
var nomansland = "ok";
attempt( function (){ return  nomansland} );
```

Comment: All this answer is is a getter paradigm. A getter/setter paradigm may be the best way to handle the situation if we assume async or protected vars in external code as a valid reason, if we assume we want to support the oddness of the original question. I'd go bonkers looking for where the var is set originally in someone else's code only to find they were being overly clever. The other answers are correct in intent, but wrong to say it's impossible. :)