# angular.isDefined vs typeof

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This question is specific to angular.isDefined() being named isDefined. We don't expect it to find a way to return false if the variable passed to it is not defined rather than throwing an uncaught error. I am looking for an angular equivalent of typeof operator to detect the not **Defined** variables.In the below example `x` is not **Defined** and `typeof x` doesn't throw any `Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined` error.where in if i had used `angular.isDefined` i would have received a `not defined error`.

```
 if(typeof x != 'undefined')
     alert("defined");
 else 
      alert("undefined");
```

**angular.isDefined(x)**  throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined` if x is not **Defined** .

```
  if(angular.isDefined(x)) // throws error because x is not defined
     alert("defined");
 else 
      alert("undefined");
```

---

```
     var x;
      if(angular.isDefined(x)) // does not throw error as x is defined though not **initialiased** 
         alert("defined");
      else 
         alert("undefined");
```

Is there an angular alternative to `typeof x !='undefined'`.Let me explain how am i ending up with this scenario.I have `createContext()` function in a js file which i am not allowed to modify.and this function defines `context="something useful"`and i have two controllers  `commonController` and `contextController`.`commonController` is executed first and registers for an custom eventhandler which needs access to `context` .then `commonController` executes which calls `createContext()` .sometimes depending on  the execution time even before the `createContext()` is called.the eventHadler is triggered and would try to access the variable which is not yet defined. I can not call `createContext()` anywhere else other than in `contextController`.

Comment: No, there is not. But I can't see any case where the difference matters, since your variables will probably always be declared.

Comment: yes i have a scenario wherein the code inside a  event subscribing block `$on` is accessing a variable defined in another function which may be executing at that moment and has not finished executing.

Comment: @Blackhole there is a little difference i checked the Doc of angular.

Comment: @DivyaMV that's impossible, JavaScript is single threaded hence either the `$on` will be executed before or after the code it needs access to.

Comment: @DivyaMV A variable doesn't go in and out of scope depending on whether a function has executed or not (unless you're adding properties to the `window` object or something like that). The scenario you are describing makes zero sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to pass undeclared variables as parameters in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104997/is-it-possible-to-pass-undeclared-variables-as-parameters-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have now clarified in the comments in @squiroid's answer, your `canvasDesign` function looks like this:

```
canvasDesign = function() { 
    var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1"); 
    if(canvas1 != null) context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
}
```

That function is creating an [implicit global variable](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) (because it's not using `var` on `context1`).

That is a *bad practice*, which is forbidden in ES5 strict mode, and the correct thing to do is to fix the code to stop using antipractices. If that is not an option, your best bet is to continue to use `typeof context1 === 'undefined'`. As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104997/is-it-possible-to-pass-undeclared-variables-as-parameters-in-javascript) clarifies, it's impossible to create a general function to check for the existence of a variable.

Two other options:

- Use `angular.isDefined(window.context1)`. This will allow you to check for a global variable without throwing an error, but this approach will break if at some point the variable is made non-global.
- Put `var context1;` at the top of your file, outside any functions. This will ensure that the variable is at least declared, and allow you to call `angular.isDefined(context1)` safely.

Answer (score 2):

angular.isDefined(obj) is not a complete substitute for typeof.

isDefined according to [doc](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L512) :

```
function isDefined(value) {return typeof value !== 'undefined';}
```

Which clearly represent it is just using typeof on the backend but with reference strict type checking(!== not !=).

So in your case typeof is working while angular.isDefined() not.

PS:- Depend on your requirement you can use typeof or angular.isDefined().

Comment: `return typeof value !== 'undefined';` should give me `false` in both cases 1) x is defined and not initialised `var x` and 2)x is not defined.But why is it throwing an error when x is not defined

Comment: Good explanation is here http://www.tagwith.com/question_1333117_angular-isdefinedobj-doesnt-work-if-obj-is-undefined

Comment: I was missing this  point **passing a variable to a function will result in trying to read the value of the variable and hence throw an error if it does not exist**

Comment: So, I guess there is no alternative for typeof value != 'undefined'; but you can define your own function to do it :-P As angular is doing the same behind the picture.

Comment: @DivyaMV If you are using `typeof value != 'undefined'` to check whether _your own variables_ are declared or not, then there is probably a problem with your code.

Comment: @DivyaMV Can you show us what your `createContext()` function looks like? As I've already said, whether or not a variable _exists_ is not dependent on the calling or not calling of a function, unless it is adding the variable to `window` or something like that. Is that what it's doing?

Comment: @JLRishe its something like this.`canvasDesign = function() { 
 var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
 if(canvas1 != null)
  context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');}`

Comment: @DivyaMV Yeah, that explains it. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question "Is there an angular alternative to `typeof x !='undefined'`" doesn't make sense.

The way JavaScript (irrespective of Angular) works is that it would be an error to do the following:

```
function foo(x){ return true; }
foo(a); // this will cause "Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined"
```

Angular's `isDefined` is a function, like any other, and when invoked with an undeclared variable, causes an error.